# I am using uamp android media player for my app when internet disconnects song changed to pause state

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-music-player

I am using uamp android media player for my app streaming hls url when internet disconnects song stops play while reconnecting it song does not play even though clicking on play button ,how can i play the song when internet connection is back